# Map Issue in React - this.state.Data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble to map the object in ReactJS.

I am fetching the data but once going map it give me error:
**this.state.Data.map is not a function**

### My Code is following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
 import './orderform.css';
import axios from 'axios';
class Orderform extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      data:[]
     };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/itemgroup/get-itemgroup')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
           this.setState({ data: res.data });
               })

        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
           }

    render() { 
             return (

           <div>
             <ul>
               {this.state.data.map((itemgroup => {
               return <li key={itemgroup._id}>{itemgroup.item_group_name}</li>
               }))}
             </ul>

           </div>

            );
    }
}

export default Orderform;
```

That's what my error page looks like:
[image: Error page]

Comment: What gets logged when you console.log res.data?

Comment: I guess you should use `res.data.data` instead (lol)

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching data inside componentDidMount, which means that the component is already mounted and trying to get this.state.data which is still an empty array because the fetching is done after mounting.
Make sure that you have the data you are trying to pass in your jsx :

```
<div>
   <ul>
      {this.state.data.length > 0
         && this.state.data.map(itemgroup => (
            <li key={itemgroup._id}>
               {itemgroup.item_group_name}
            </li>
         ))
      }
    </ul>
</div>
```

ps. arrow functions return the value by default

Comment: orderform1.js:39 Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
orderform1.js:25 undefined
orderform1.js:39 Objectitemgroup: Array(2)0: {_id: "5dc9c99e1c9d440000479fb1", item_group_id: 1, item_group_name: "Starter"}1: {_id: "5dc9d75ff110a1105ceee35e", item_group_id: 2, item_group_name: "Soup", isenabled: true, createdAt: "2019-11-11T21:49:19.883Z", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)success: true__proto__: Object